# C++ third party library typedef conflicts with standard stdin.h

Tags: c++

### The issue

I'm attempting to write a program that listens to audio streams created using [JACK audio server](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2). The package works fine when consumed on it's own, however when I attempt to use it in a file alongside a reference to a standard c++ lib such as iostream, typedef conflict errors are thrown between the 3rd party lib and stdint.h.

For the file, I'm using `jack/jack.h` and `jack/types.h`, both from the JACK package. They include references to the `systemdeps.h` file (expanded on below), which is the source of the error.

I've attempted to find solutions online, however nothing seems to work. Any insights into what may be causing this, or a point in the right direction to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

#### Error messages

```
2>\Jack\includes\jack/systemdeps.h(69): error C2371: 'int8_t': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)

2>stdint.h(17): note: see declaration of 'int8_t' (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)

2>\Jack\includes\jack/systemdeps.h(73): error C2371: 'int32_t': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)

2>stdint.h(19): note: see declaration of 'int32_t' (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)

2>\Jack\includes\jack/systemdeps.h(74): error C2371: 'uint32_t': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)

2>stdint.h(23): note: see declaration of 'uint32_t' (compiling source file src\jack\jack_interface.cpp)
```

#### My implementation

```
// jack_interface.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "jack/jack.h"                // Core library .h
#include "jack/types.h"               // library types .h
#include "jack/jack_interface.h"      // My .h extending the lib

namespace jack 
{
}
```

This is the bare minimum I can write to cause the errors to be thrown.

jack_interface.h is empty.

jack.h and types.h both include references to systemdeps.h, where the conflict is being created.

The errors are **only** thrown when both the library and any standard C++ file that references stdint.h are both included, e.g. iostream. If I remove iostream, the library functions 100%.

The libraries I'm using from the 3rd party package are for 32 bit Windows. I'm compiling for 32 bit using Visual Studio 2017.

#### systemdeps.h

The library header file where the conflicts are being thrown. The lines throwing the errors have been marked below. [See file on github here.](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/blob/master/common/jack/systemdeps.h)

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(GNU_WIN32)

#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER     /* Microsoft compiler */
    #define __inline__ inline
    #if (!defined(int8_t) && !defined(_STDINT_H))
        #define __int8_t_defined
        typedef char int8_t;                 <-- ERROR
        typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
        typedef short int16_t;
        typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
        typedef long int32_t;                <-- ERROR
        typedef unsigned long uint32_t;      <-- ERROR
        typedef LONGLONG int64_t;
        typedef ULONGLONG uint64_t;
    #endif
```

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the library developers.

Comment: The only thing you can do is implement a facade in your code for this library that only includes their header files, and your header file with your facade's interface, then write your main C++ code to use the facade.

Comment: You can try defining `_STDINT_H` as a workaround. Or maybe it is supposed to be defined though a config header of some kind. `systemdeps.h` file is a total mess...

Comment: Just guessing, but if you add `#include <stdint.h>` before any of those Jack headers the problem will probably be fixed. That way you'll get the definitions of those types from `<stdint.h>` as well as the include guard (assuming that they're right that the name of the include guard is `_STDINT_H`).

Comment: @PeteBecker Checking the referenced `stdint.h`, the guard is `_STDINT`, not `STDINT_H`! Doh! Will definetely contact the developers. Thanks much - never would have figured this out myself.
Is it worth adding this as an answer? Or just closing the Q?

Comment: Chris and @PeteBecker: it is worth promoting Pete's comment to an answer. It can be really useful to people using Jack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `”systemdeps.h”`does a rather bad job of providing those typedefs. From your comment, it’s checking for the wrong include guard. Even if it was right, you’d run into problems if you included `<stdint.h>` after that header. So you have to do two things. First, wherever you use any of those `jack` headers, add `#include <stdint.h>` **before** you include the `jack` headers. And second, immediately after `#include <stdint.h>` add `#define _STDINT_H`. That way you get the typedefs from the compiler’s header and you tell `”systemdeps.h”` not to provide its own definitions. That’s tedious and error-prone, so you might consider creating your own header that does all of that in one place.